# VBA default types for literals?

Tags: vba

If i use like 2.214 or "string" as literal values in my code, what their default types would be?
2.214 will be double and "string" will be fixed length string? or how do compiler knows?

Comment: Yes. 2.214  must be a double (`Dim ... As Double`), and the "literals" part must be 'Dim ... As String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler knows the data type based on how you write 2.214 in your code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestIt()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = 2.214
    Debug.Print TypeName(v)
    v = "2.214"
    Debug.Print TypeName(v)
End Sub
```

But unfortunately a lof of [implicit data type casting](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/converting-implicit-conversion.htm) is done. So this code is also valid

```
Dim d As Double
d = "2.214"
```

But be aware, the string "2.214" is converted into a double and the outcome might depend on locale settings.

Comment: You can also force literals to a specific type by postfixing a 1 letter type descriptor  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters